# How to change the color of a full collapsible-ul(Materialize,Html,Javascript,Css)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, materialize

I have 2 collapsible-lists and 2 buttons, if I click on the first button, the color of all headers of the second `<ul>` should change (for example green) and if I click on the second button the color of all bodys in the second `<ul>` should change (for example black).

I'm searching for a solution in JavaScript (jQuery also possible). The Problem is that I'm new in all of this and have no idea how to solve this task. I'm thankful for every help.

### My code

```
 <ul class="collapsible" id="1">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>

 <ul class="collapsible" id="2">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
<button class="btn yellow" id="collapsible-header-green">Change collor of all headers ul(id="2")</button>
<button class="btn yellow" id="collapsible-body-green"> Change collor of all bodys ul(id="2")</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On buttton click add or remove css class:

```
$('#collapsible-header-green').on('click', function() {
    if($('#2 .red-header').length > 0) {
        $('#2 .collapsible-header').removeClass('red-header');
    } else {
        $('#2 .collapsible-header').addClass('red-header');
    }               
});
          
$('#collapsible-body-green').on('click', function() {
    if($('#2 .green-body').length > 0) {
        $('#2 .collapsible-body').removeClass('green-body');
    } else {
        $('#2 .collapsible-body').addClass('green-body');
    }
});

<style>
  .red-header {
    color: red;
  }
  
  .green-body {
    color: green;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I´m thankfull for your help but this change's only the color of text, do you know how to change the background of the header/body?

Comment: `background-color`?

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: like this: https://dojo.telerik.com/UzakORat

Comment: Yes I have tried it in the same way like in the link but it doesn't work. It seems like materialize is the problem.